# Calling GetFileAttributesW() removes a pipe

Tags: c++, winapi

I create a pipe (//./pipe/mycoolpipe) with a very long timeout, from process A,

```
pipe = ::CreateNamedPipe(
        name_.c_str(),
        direction_,
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        ...,
        ...,
        PIPE_TIMEOUT,
    );
```

MS sysinternals pipelist.exe is enumerating my pipe:

```
pipelist.exe | grep mycoolpipe
 //./pipe/mycoolpipe
```

then from process B I'd like to read the file attributes:

```
::GetFileAttributesW(p.c_str()) // p == //./pipe/mycoolpipe
```

and right after calling GetFileAttributesW, **the pipe is gone - WHAT? WHY?**

Note: debbuging proved executing *GetFileAttributesW* makes the pipe gone -  pipelist.exe is not enumerating it any more right after calling *GetFileAttributesW* . Timeout is not involved.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the pipe using `CreateFile` after the pipe is "gone"? Just check the systinternals tool is giving correct information.

Comment: Yes I've tried, CreateFile returns invalid_handle_value after the pipe is "gone": while (CreateFile() == invalid) retry; // never leaves the loop

Comment: Why are you calling `GetFileAttributesW()` on a pipe to begin with?

Comment: @Remy Is there a reason why GetFileAttributesW() should be illegal on a pipe? I'm calling it from the other process under the hood of boost::is_directory

Comment: @MichalWegorek: per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944.aspx): "Retrieves **file system attributes** for a specified file or directory.". A pipe is not part of the file system. Why are you calling `boost::is_directory()` on something that is not related to the filesystem in the first place?

Comment: @Remy I'm validating the input from the user and it's a step of that  validation. Anyway, Windows should handle invalid paths without breaking the object pointed by the path.

Comment: If you really need to call `is_directory`, you'll have to check whether the path starts \\.\ first and reject such paths.  But it seems to me that if you've asked for a path to a file and the user has given you a path to a pipe, it's the user's fault when it breaks stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetFileAttributesW()` has undefined behavior for non-filesystem objects, so just don't do it.

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin.patches/1973

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2004-q2/msg00193.html

> But, while //server/pipe/name may be a UNC path, it is not a path to a file. 
>   And certain Win32 functions (**including GetFileAttributes**) do not work on 
>   those paths. When I say "do not work", I mean the Win32 SDK actually says 
>   not to call them on those paths, and when I do it on my XP Pro SP1 (with all 
>   updates), odd behavior ensues. **This is undefined behavior. Sometimes I can 
>   see weird stuff at the filesystem level using SysInternals' FileMon.**

> GetFileAttributes behavior is not defined for pipe paths. So it cannot be called on those paths. I believe it returns -1 on my XP system - after it opens and closes the pipe, changing the semantics for the server! But there's no guarantee what it would return on other systems.
>
> What we're up against here is a failing of the Win32 API:
>   1) **GetFileAttributes cannot be called on a pipe path.**
>   2) There is no function that can tell you that a path is a pipe path unless you actually open it and use GetFileType - which changes server semantics.
>   3) **Therefore, you have to detect pipe paths and avoid calling GetFileAttributes.**